# How to transform a tuple element values in a list of two tuple using map

Tags: scala

I have the following:

```
val x : List[(String, Int)] = List((mealOne,2), (mealTWo,1), (mealThree,2))
```

I want to replace or transform the String to Int using the below values with  a map:

val mealOne = 5.99; val mealTwo = 6.99; val mealThree = 7.99

```
x.map{ x => if (x._1 == "mealOne") mealOne
                      else if (x._1 == "mealTwo") mealTwo 
                      else   mealThree
               }
```

Result:

```
List[Double] = List(5.99, 6.99, 7.99)
```

but I want this:

```
List[Double,Int] = List((5.99,2), (6.99,1), (7.99,2))
```

So how can I achieve the above

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just don't drop the second component of the tuple then:

```
x.map{ x => (
  if (x._1 == "mealOne") mealOne
  else if (x._1 == "mealTwo") mealTwo 
  else mealThree,
  x._2
)}
```

of course, it works for arbitrary mappings from `String`s to `Double`s:

```
def replaceNamesByPrices(
  nameToPrice: String => Double, 
  xs: List[(String, Int)]
): List[(Double, Int)] = 
  for ((name, amount) <- xs) yield (nameToPrice(name), amount)
```

so that you can then store the mapping of names to prices in a map, i.e.

```
val priceTable = Map(
  "mealOne" -> 42.99, 
  "mealTwo" -> 5.99, 
  "mealThree" -> 2345.65
)
```

so that

```
replaceNamesByPrices(priceTable, x)
```

yields the desired result.

Comment: But my doubt is how it can be maintainable in future if some other tuple value like `("mealFour",4)`etc is to be added to list x and a corresponding value of replacement as 8.99 or so. How can we manage existing code if we had used `if`'s in code. it needs to be revised every time when some other data is added.isn't it?

Comment: @RAGHHURAAMM Cut out all the magic `if-else`-nonsense, replace by a generic function. Then appropriate data structure (e.g. `Map` of some kind) to implement the function.

Comment: Yes. that's working fine, except for the little typo in `replaceNamesByPrices(nameToPrice, x)` to be corrected as `replaceNamesByPrices(namesToPrice, x)`

Comment: @RAGHHURAAMM Thanks, fixed. Changed both identifiers to something that will not be confused with the argument name.

Answer (score 0):

This works in this way:(still simplified, thanks to Andrey Tyukin):

```
for(m<-x) yield (y(m._1),m._2)
for((m,n)<-x) yield (y(m),n)
```

or

```
x.map(t=>(y(t._1),t._2))
x.map{case (m,n)=>(y(m),n)}
```

Your Lists ( input ):(y is changed to Map)

```
val x  = List(("mealOne",2), ("mealTWo",1), ("mealThree",2))
val y  = Map(("mealOne",5.99), ("mealTWo",6.99), ("mealThree",7.99))
```

### In Scala REPL:

```
scala> for(m<-x) yield (y(m._1),m._2)
res35: List[(Double, Int)] = List((5.99,2), (6.99,1), (7.99,2))
scala> for((m,n)<-x) yield (y(m),n)
res60: List[(Double, Int)] = List((5.99,2), (6.99,1), (7.99,2))
scala> x.map(t=>(y(t._1),t._2))
res57: List[(Double, Int)] = List((5.99,2), (6.99,1), (7.99,2))
scala> x.map{case (m,n)=>(y(m),n)}
res59: List[(Double, Int)] = List((5.99,2), (6.99,1), (7.99,2)
```

)

Comment: @ RAGHHURAAMM Thanks for you and

Comment: It's `O(|x| * |y|)` :/